# Pick jQuery contains string

Tags: jquery

```
var className = this.id;
if (className == 'pet-sitting' || className == 'walking' || className == 'mobile-grooming')
{}
```

Above className can have any values such as 'pet-sitting2' or 'pet-sitting3' or 'pet-sitting4' or etc.

My question is I have to Trim above className only for the 'pet-sitting' scenarios where it fits for the above if statement.How can I achieve that ?

Comment: You are looking for ID or CLASS attribute???

Comment: if (className == 'pet-sitting')
{} Not sure what is our exact question :D

Comment: @A.Wolff Actually I assign the 'this.id' value to the variable 'className'.

Comment: You should provide more about context in your question, maybe you are just looking for: `$('[class*="pet-sitting"],[class*="walking"]')`

Comment: How are you selecting `this`? Why not filter with the selection logic like @A.Wolff's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use The `indexOf()` method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.Hope this hels u mate.. :)

This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

```
var className = this.id;
if(className.indexOf('pet-sitting') > -1) {
     //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using replace() along with regex

```
this.id.replace(/pet-sitting.+/g, "pet-sitting");
```

*regex:* ***`.+`*** means one or character